# Python escape character when parameter is a path - Windows

Tags: python, methods, input, parameters, path

I am relatively new to python, and I am writing a method for a toolbox I am creating.

The function is something like this:

```
def explodeByUniqueAttributeValue(inputfile,fieldname,outputworkspace):
...
```

When the path of the input file or the workspace have specific escape characters such as \t the function does not work. 
More specifically the input file might be something like this:

```
"C:\tmp\Data\Data.dbf"
```

and the outputworkspace might be something like this:

```
"D:\Data\2010_12\Output"
```

In these cases what python reads is accordingly:

```
>>> inputfile    
C:\tmp\\Data\\Data.dbf   

>>> print inputfile    
C:  mp\Data\Data.dbf
```

and

```
>>> outputworkspace  
'D:\\Data\x810_12\\Output'   
>>> print outputworkspace
D:\Dataﾁ0_12\Output
```

My Question is:
Is there any way to parse the input parameters of a functions as raw strings, the same way this can be done when the assignment of the file and the output workspace is done through a variable in a script
*i.e.*

```
inputfile = r"C:\tmp\Data\Data.dbf"
outputworkspace = r"D:\Data\2010_12\Output"
```

or any function applied to the parameters that will return them to a generic format?
I have tried so far os.path.normpath() or string.encode()

for the issue with the inputfile I have found the way to get around it by the following:

```
Dummy = inputfile.replace('\t','\\t'); inputfile = Dummy; del Dummy
```

Which I can repeat for all the escape characters or create another method that does exactly this, but the same cannot be done for the

```
"\2010_12"
```

escape which is "read" by python as

```
"\x810_12"
```

Since it wouldn't be the "proper" way to program

I have already read solutions such as using "/" or "\\", but I am wondering if there is any way to pass the input parameters of a method as raw themselves.

Adding an example:

```
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
import os

def printpaths(file,outputworkspace):
    print file
    print outputworkspace

printpaths('C:\tmp\Data\Data.dbf','D:\Data\2010_12\Data')
```

Help would be greatly appreciated
Thanx in advance

Comment: They don't need to be; you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: The notion of "raw" vs. "cooked" only applies to string literals, not to the string objects they denote or strings in general.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams
Is there any way to narrow down what am I doing wrong?
Might it have to do with encoding? Recently I started using VS 2010 and Tools for python, that might have changed the encoding from 'ascii' to 'utf8'.

Comment: The "the issue with the inputfile I have found the way to get around it by the following:" doesn't actually exist for user input, arguments to functions, or anything **except** the source code of a script.  You appears to be confused by the things you see at the `>>>` prompt.  If you write a three-line script to open a file based on user inputs, you'll see that there is no actual problem.

Comment: @S.Lott Currently I am writing and running everything through Visual Studio 2010 and Tools for Python, so indeed I do run through this issue whenever one of these 2 paths are input to another function. 
Indeed I am confused with the things that I see in the **prompt** as I thought that whatever is the output of print is each parameter itself. Forgive my confusion, but I come from a matlab background that things with variables and input parameters are straightforward.

Comment: These things are straightforward.  At the Python `>>>` prompt, extra `\` must be inserted so that the string is valid Python syntax.  When running an application (from the command line, not from the `>>>` prompt) the extra `\` is NOT inserted because the output is NOT in Python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the paths from? input from a user?

In that case, there are ways:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, May  6 2011, 10:39:37) 
[GCC 3.3.3 (SuSE Linux)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> raw_input("filename: ")
filename: C:\tmp
'C:\\tmp'
>>> raw_input("output: ")
output: D:\Data\2010_12\Output
'D:\\Data\\2010_12\\Output'
```

Or was it something else you were after?

Comment: The method is meant to be used on Windows, since it uses a Toolbox of a proprietary software, that only runs on the specific OS.
Additionally, since it might be called through another method, I wouldn't like to use the input() or raw_input() methods

Comment: @SergiosKolios When you say method, you don't mean a python function, do you? Because whatever strings you pass between python functions will not be "evaluated" in any way. If it contains the right data from the beginning, it will do what you want.
If it is input parameters at program start, you will need to escape it properly, otherwise the input data is just plain wrong and trying to fix it inside python is not the best solution.

Comment: Yes Indeed I mean a python function.
Generally I am trying to find a way to use this function either calling it either with parameters, or via another function/method.
_italic_ e.g.: 
def printstrings(file,outputworkspace):
    print file
    print outputworkspace